# Rails query only works randomly

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Rails query like the following:

```
Delivery.includes(delivery_products: :product)
.where('delivery_products.delivery_count > ? or delivery_products.back_count > ?', 0, 0)
.references(delivery_products: :product)
.joins(:customer).where(customers: {category: 'Auslieferer'})
.where('delivery_date >= ? AND delivery_date <= ?', from_date, to_date)
```

When I restart the Rails server the query works perfectly. After some point in time (when I visit other pages of the Rails App) the same query results in an error. I have no idea why this query works only randomly.

Here is the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'products.product_prices.price' in 'field list': 
SELECT `deliveries`.`id` AS t0_r0, 
`deliveries`.`delivery_date` AS t0_r1, `deliveries`.`price_group` AS t0_r2, 
`deliveries`.`customer_id` AS t0_r3, 
`deliveries`.`created_at` AS t0_r4, `deliveries`.`updated_at` AS t0_r5, 
`deliveries`.`invoice_id` AS t0_r6, `deliveries`.`user_id` AS t0_r7, 
`delivery_products`.`id` AS t1_r0, `delivery_products`.`product_id` AS t1_r1, `delivery_products`.`delivery_id` AS t1_r2, `delivery_products`.`delivery_count` AS t1_r3, 
`delivery_products`.`back_count` AS t1_r4, `delivery_products`.`price` AS t1_r5, `delivery_products`.`created_at` AS t1_r6, `delivery_products`.`updated_at` AS t1_r7, `products`.`id` AS t2_r0, 
`products`.`product_number` AS t2_r1, `products`.`name` AS t2_r2, `products`.`tax` AS t2_r3, `products`.`created_at` AS t2_r4, 
`products`.`updated_at` AS t2_r5, `products`.`deleted` AS t2_r6, `products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r7, `products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r8, 
`products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r9, `products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r10, `products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r11, 
`products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r12, `products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r13, `products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r14, 
`products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r15, `products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r16, `products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r17, 
`products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r18 
 FROM `deliveries` 
 INNER JOIN `customers` ON `customers`.`id` = `deliveries`.`customer_id` 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `delivery_products` ON `delivery_products`.`delivery_id` = `deliveries`.`id` 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `delivery_products`.`product_id` 
 WHERE (delivery_products.delivery_count > 0 or delivery_products.back_count > 0) AND `customers`.`category` = 'Auslieferer' AND (delivery_date >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00.000000' AND delivery_date <= '2015-10-31 23:59:59.000000')
```

I don't know why Rails is creating the following sql selects which are causing the error. The original query doesn't produce this:

```
`products`.`product_prices.price` AS t2_r7
```

Comment: Not sure what's happening, but "model behavior changes on some requests" sounds to me like something triggered by reloading. To see if that's true, you could try this: temporarily put `config.cache_classes = true` in `config/environments/development.rb`, restart the server, and see if you get consistent behavior.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. My guess is that somehow Rails is caching another query and then mixing it with the one above. Could that be the case?

Comment: Random is always hard to deal with. First step is trying to consistently repo this. Try to find the trigger where this query starts breaking so that you can isolate to the root cause. Otherwise it's just guess and check, which is a terrible way to debug!

Comment: Why is Rails producing so many `products.product_prices.pric AS t2_r7` in the first place. Can this be a Rails Bug?

Comment: I ask this because in the query above I don't ask Rails to fetch the product_prices table, but Rails is quering it anyway.